# Inner join when it should be left join in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JpaRepository and I'm creating a @Query in my repository:

this is my query:

```
@Query( "SELECT SUM(p.prima) as prima, p.producto as producto, p.tipoProducto as tipoProducto, p.compania as compania, p.cliente as cliente, p.vendedor as vendedor " +
        "FROM Poliza p " +
        "JOIN Producto pr       ON p.producto=pr " +
        "JOIN TipoProducto tp   ON p.tipoProducto=tp " +
        "JOIN Compania c        ON p.compania=c " +
        "JOIN Cliente cl        ON p.cliente=cl " +
        "LEFT JOIN Vendedor v   ON p.vendedor=v " +
        "WHERE p.comienzo >=?1 " +
        "AND p.comienzo <= ?2 " +
        "GROUP BY p.producto")
```

and I realize that I only get the rows where "Vendedor" is present.
I used the **spring.jpa.show-sql=true** property to check what was going on and I realize that the **query** is creating an **inner join** for each property in the **SELECT STATEMENT**

```
inner join producto producto1_ on (poliza0_.producto=producto1_.id) 
inner join tipo_producto tipoproduc2_ on (poliza0_.tipo_producto=tipoproduc2_.id)
inner join compania compania3_ on (poliza0_.compania=compania3_.id) 
inner join cliente cliente4_ on (poliza0_.cliente=cliente4_.id) 
inner join vendedor vendedor5_ on (poliza0_.vendedor=vendedor5_.id) 

join producto producto6_ on poliza0_.producto=producto6_.id 
join tipo_producto tipoproduc7_ on poliza0_.tipo_producto=tipoproduc7_.id 
join compania compania8_ on poliza0_.compania=compania8_.id 
join cliente cliente9_ on poliza0_.cliente=cliente9_.id 
left join vendedor vendedor10_ on poliza0_.vendedor=vendedor10_.id
```

As you can see in the first part I have an **inner join** from **Vendedor** which makes the query wrong.

How should I create my query to get the expected result?

Comment: Change the first part of `inner join vendedor` to `left join` then? By the way, without any sample data and expected result, we couldn't possibly give a precise answer to _"How should I create my query to get the expected result?"_

Comment: When selecting a relation (like `SELECT p.vendedor ...`), JPA will implicitly join with the related table. You are also *explicitly* joining with the same table, `LEFT JOIN Vendedor v ON ...`. Honestly, I would expect JPA to figure out these are the same table and do a single join in the generated SQL. Since it doesn't, why don't you just use the joined object in the select clause - `SELECT ..., v ... LEFT JOIN Vendedor v ...`?

Comment: @FanoFN the "inner joins" are implicitly created when I add the `SELECT STATEMENT...` . As you can see in my query I don't add those "inner join" JPA add it itself

Since `Vendedor` is a column in `Poliza` (FK) which could be null, I need a `LEFT JOIN` instead `INNER JOIN` to get the row even though this column is null.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos If I use only the `INNER JOIN` implicitly added if the value of `Vendedor` is null this row will not appear. I need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to have these values too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if understand clearly

```
@Query( "SELECT SUM(p.prima) as prima, p.producto as producto, p.tipoProducto as tipoProducto, p.compania as compania, p.cliente as cliente, p.vendedor as vendedor " +
        "FROM Poliza p " +
        "JOIN Producto pr       ON p.producto=pr " +
        "JOIN TipoProducto tp   ON p.tipoProducto=tp " +
        "JOIN Compania c        ON p.compania=c " +
        "JOIN Cliente cl        ON p.cliente=cl " +
        "LEFT JOIN Vendedor v   ON p.vendedor=v " +
        "WHERE p.comienzo >=?1 " +
        "AND p.comienzo <= ?2 " +
        "GROUP BY p.producto")
```

i think you can using `v` instead `p.vendedor as vendedor` in select field.

Comment: I changed to `v` and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly, you are defining your own query. So, you can edit the JOIN in your query and write LEFT JOIN instead.
Am I right on your intentions?